Need to Extract ContentCreated and DateLastSaved from 1000s of Microsoft Office files
I am a digital records archivist and working to extract metadata from thousands upon thousands of old employee records for my company -- over 30 years of records.
Due to a few errors/oversights, the Date Created and Date Modified fields recorded for all files are no longer accurate for any of these files. Date Created reflects the date records were copied (not robocopied!) over to the archived servers, and the Date Modified reflects a decryption date in 2023. I haven't lost hope though. About 85% of the files are Microsoft Office records with accurate ContentCreated and DateLastSaved timestamps embedded within the file details:

The only problem is that I cannot uniformly get that information out via powershell.
I was previously able to use the Get-FileMetadata function from this old StackOverflow post to retrieve this data from every applicable file in a directory: Is it possible to extract metadata such as Content Created date from files - I can't get this with PowerShell
For some reason, it doesn't work correctly anymore. I have been testing on one folder of ALL Microsoft Word 97-2003 .doc files. Every single one of them has the same fields stored in file properties. Less than half are exporting the ContentCreated, DateLastSaved, and file path information. All are exporting the name.
To illustrate what has worked previously, first I enter the script
function Get-FileMetaData {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Small function that gets metadata information from file providing similar output to what Explorer shows when viewing file
    .DESCRIPTION
    Small function that gets metadata information from file providing similar output to what Explorer shows when viewing file
    .PARAMETER File
    FileName or FileObject
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Force | Get-FileMetaData | Out-HtmlView -ScrollX -Filtering -AllProperties
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Force | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -like '*Hidden*' } | Get-FileMetaData | Out-HtmlView -ScrollX -Filtering -AllProperties
    .NOTES
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)][Object] $File,
        [switch] $Signature
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($F in $File) {
            $MetaDataObject = [ordered] @{}
            if ($F -is [string]) {
                $FileInformation = Get-ItemProperty -Path $F
            } elseif ($F -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                #Write-Warning "Get-FileMetaData - Directories are not supported. Skipping $F."
                continue
            } elseif ($F -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
                $FileInformation = $F
            } else {
                Write-Warning "Get-FileMetaData - Only files are supported. Skipping $F."
                continue
            }
            $ShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
            $ShellFolder = $ShellApplication.Namespace($FileInformation.Directory.FullName)
            $ShellFile = $ShellFolder.ParseName($FileInformation.Name)
            $MetaDataProperties = [ordered] @{}
            0..400 | ForEach-Object -Process {
                $DataValue = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)
                $PropertyValue = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($DataValue.Trim()).Replace(' ', '')
                if ($PropertyValue -ne '') {
                    $MetaDataProperties["$_"] = $PropertyValue
                }
            }
            foreach ($Key in $MetaDataProperties.Keys) {
                $Property = $MetaDataProperties[$Key]
                $Value = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile, [int] $Key)
                if ($Property -in 'Attributes', 'Folder', 'Type', 'SpaceFree', 'TotalSize', 'SpaceUsed') {
                    continue
                }
                If (($null -ne $Value) -and ($Value -ne '')) {
                    $MetaDataObject["$Property"] = $Value
                }
            }
            if ($FileInformation.VersionInfo) {
                $SplitInfo = ([string] $FileInformation.VersionInfo).Split([char]13)
                foreach ($Item in $SplitInfo) {
                    $Property = $Item.Split(":").Trim()
                    if ($Property[0] -and $Property[1] -ne '') {
                        $MetaDataObject["$($Property[0])"] = $Property[1]
                    }
                }
            }
            $MetaDataObject["Attributes"] = $FileInformation.Attributes
            $MetaDataObject['IsReadOnly'] = $FileInformation.IsReadOnly
            $MetaDataObject['IsHidden'] = $FileInformation.Attributes -like '*Hidden*'
            $MetaDataObject['IsSystem'] = $FileInformation.Attributes -like '*System*'
            if ($Signature) {
                $DigitalSignature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $FileInformation.Fullname
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateSubject'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.Subject
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateIssuer'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.Issuer
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateSerialNumber'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.SerialNumber
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateNotBefore'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.NotBefore
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateNotAfter'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.NotAfter
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureCertificateThumbprint'] = $DigitalSignature.SignerCertificate.Thumbprint
                $MetaDataObject['SignatureStatus'] = $DigitalSignature.Status
                $MetaDataObject['IsOSBinary'] = $DigitalSignature.IsOSBinary
            }
            [PSCustomObject] $MetaDataObject
        }
    }
}

And then I gather the file info I want and export to csv
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-FileMetadata | Select-Object Path,ContentCreated,DateLastSaved | Export-Csv "Path.csv"
Any help would be appreciated, whether it's fixing the problem or finding an entirely new solution. I'm officially stumped and at max-capacity of my powershell skillset.

Just an observation: when I ran your code (unaltered) against a small number of doc/docx files, each data part (day, month year) in the output .csv was preceded by a Unicode Left-to-right marker ( U+200E). I don't know if that's normal for the powershell modules your code is using, and in fact the dates display fine if I open the .csv in Notepad (say) but I just wondered whether it might be interfering with your ability to view the results. Think I've seen this before but I don't use PS much.

I too would work backwards and ensure that something is being displayed for those properties before exporting to ensure it's not an encoding issue. Other than that, here's an article that aims to do the same thing. I was able to run the 2nd solution just not the first since it required a download. On a separate note, I would place the COMObject instantiation inside the BEGIN block.

@jonsson Yes! There has always been an interesting issue with the output for these fields. Previously I was getting "??" wrapped into the date/timestamp, but every file's stamp was still exporting. Now I'm getting a different character when I open in excel, and only select records are exporting information. I don't think they're interfering with the ability to view the results because when I run the script and have it write the output in PS, I get the same results without the odd characters.

@AbrahamZinala I saw this spiceworks article the other day as well, but ran into trouble trying to understand/install/access the specific DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties COM object mentioned. When looking further into it before submitting the request to download/install to my IT dept, I came across pages that said this DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties was obsolete so I was wary about tying my solution to it.
I'm not sure I understand the last part of your comment, if you don't mind clarifying.

@KendallAughenbaugh, theres an alternate solution using Expand-Archive but can come at a cost of computational expense. As for my comment regarding the BEGIN block/header. See this article.
